# how to loop over two json arrays and filter results in karate?

Tags: arrays, json, automation, karate

I have 2JSON Arrays

```
a= [{"[{ "Id": "123","Types": "Dial"},{"Id": "963", "Types": "Post"},{"Id": "456","Types": "Dial"},
  { "Id": "569","Types": "Dial"}]
```

```
 b= [{"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": "Identifier","Id": "123"}]}},
    {"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": "Identifier" ,"Id": "569"}]}},
    {"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": null,"Id": "963"}]}},
    {"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": null,"Id": "963"}]}},
    {"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": null,"Id": "963"}]}},
    {"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": null,"Id": "963"}]}},
    {"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": "Identifier","Id": "456"}]}}]
```

I want to verify from 'a' if the "Types" value is "POST", for the corresponding "id" in JSON "b"  "Type" has value "null"

please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using Json-path integration with karate or you can also use filter function.

```
* def IdArray = karate.jsonPath(a,"$..[?(@.Types=="Post")].Id")  
* def FilteredArray = call FilterFunction(IdArray,b)
```

And you can define the filter function as

```
* def FilterFunction =
"""
function(arr,b)
{ var result = []
 for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
   { var Mypath = "$..[?(@.Id==\""+ arr[i] +"\")].Type"
     var newArr = karate.jsonPath(b,Mypath)
     karate.apend(result,newArr)
   }
 return result
}
""""
```

So that filteredArray will contain all the null values. Just apply the check on that array for null values.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The filter function is returning an empty array. I followed the same code as mentioned. tried with different JSON arrays too.